# Ray Tune conflicting with the `breakpoint()` function

Tags: python, pycharm, breakpoints, ray, ray-tune

The code section attached below, which is basically copy-pasted from the [official documentation of Ray Tune](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/key-concepts.html) runs as expected until the last line, but calling `breakpoint()` after `tuner.fit()` breaks the debugger (I can't see any call stack or local variables in PyCharm's debugger), and prints the following warning:

```
PYDEV DEBUGGER WARNING:
sys.settrace() should not be used when the debugger is being used.
This may cause the debugger to stop working correctly.
If this is needed, please check: 
http://pydev.blogspot.com/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html
to see how to restore the debug tracing back correctly.
Call Location:
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\bdb.py", line 334, in set_trace
    sys.settrace(self.trace_dispatch)

*** Temporarily disabling Ray worker logs ***
--Return--
> c:\users\username\appdata\local\jetbrains\toolbox\apps\pycharm-p\ch-0\223.7571.203\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_breakpointhook.py(13)pydevd_breakpointhook()->None
-> sys.__breakpointhook__(*args, **kwargs)
(Pdb) 
>?
```

How could I solve the issue and make the `breakpoint()` function and the debugger work as expected?

I'm using PyCharm, Python 3.8.10, Windows 10.

## main.py

```
from ray import tune
from ray.tune.search.bayesopt import BayesOptSearch
from ray import air
from ray.air import session

def objective(x, a, b):  # Define an objective function.
    return a * (x**0.5) + b


def trainable(config):  # Pass a "config" dictionary into your trainable.

    for x in range(20):  # "Train" for 20 iterations and compute intermediate scores.
        score = objective(x, config["a"], config["b"])

        session.report({"score": score})  # Send the score to Tune.


# Define the search space
search_space = {"a": tune.uniform(0, 1), "b": tune.uniform(0, 20)}

algo = BayesOptSearch(random_search_steps=4)

tuner = tune.Tuner(
    trainable,
    tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
        metric="score",
        mode="min",
        search_alg=algo,
    ),
    run_config=air.RunConfig(stop={"training_iteration": 20}),
    param_space=search_space,
)

breakpoint()  # works as expected

r = tuner.fit()

breakpoint()  # raises warning
```

## requirements.txt

```
pip==21.3.1
setuptools==60.2.0
wheel==0.37.1
ray[tune]==2.2.0
bayesian-optimization==1.4.2
```

## What have I tried?

Inside the PDB session, using [traceback.print_stack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack) I get the following:

```
  ... pydev/pydevd.py ...
  File "C:\Repos\RayTune\main.py", line 38, in <module>
    breakpoint()  # raises warning
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\223.7571.203\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_breakpointhook.py", line 27, in breakpointhook
    pydevd_breakpointhook()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\223.7571.203\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_breakpointhook.py", line 13, in pydevd_breakpointhook
    sys.__breakpointhook__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\bdb.py", line 92, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\bdb.py", line 151, in dispatch_return
    self.user_return(frame, arg)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pdb.py", line 294, in user_return
    self.interaction(frame, None)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pdb.py", line 357, in interaction
    self._cmdloop()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pdb.py", line 322, in _cmdloop
    self.cmdloop()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\cmd.py", line 138, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pdb.py", line 423, in onecmd
    return cmd.Cmd.onecmd(self, line)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\cmd.py", line 216, in onecmd
    return self.default(line)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pdb.py", line 381, in default
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

`locals()` evaluate to:

```
{'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'hookname': 'ray.util.rpdb._driver_set_trace', '__return__': None, 'traceback': <module 'traceback' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\traceback.py'>}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As the error message says usually there's no need to use pdb when you're using the PyCharm debugger. Have you tried [reading the post in the error message](https://pydev.blogspot.com/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html)? It should work if you just use the debugger without pdb.

Comment: @bad_coder Thank you for replying! I agree there is no need to use pdb inside PyCharm. That's the problem, usually `breakpoint()` activate pydevd, but after using ray.tune it's broken and for some reason fail to pdb. I've tried to read the linked post, it gives a reasonable explanation of the issue, but I couldn't see any relevant solution.

Anyway, after reading your comment, I tried using `pydevd.settrace()` instead of `breakpoint()`, and it works! So until someone will reply with a better solution, you're invited to post this as an answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks!